# The symmetric of a real function with respect to a line

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

Let consider the function $$f(t)=a t^2+b$$,
and the line $D$ defined by $$y=mx+p$$ such that the constants  $(a,b,m,p$) are real and $(a\neq 0,b\neq 0,m\neq 0,p\neq 0)$

What is the expression of the function $g$  such that $g$ and $f$ are symmetric with respect to $D$ ?

Comment: Depending on the parameters, the curve symmetric to the graph of $f$ relative to $D$ might not be the graph of a function of $t$ at all, e.g., $a=1, b=0, m=1, p=0$. I think you should take a look at [reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thanks, yes  as far as I know the condition that all the parameter are nor zeros the symmetric will be a function (but we can think just when the symmetric is a function )

Comment: HINT.- 1) Take an arbitrary point $P$ in the parabola; 2) Draw from point $P$ the perpendicular to the line that will be crossed at point $Q$; 3) Calculate the distance $d$ between points $P$ and $Q$; 4) Calculate the position of the point $P'$ opposed to $P$ on the perpendicular such that $QP'=d$. Point $P'$ will be a generic point of the symmetric curve sought.